# Finding the probability of success for a population proportion with an example.

Tags: probability, statistics

This question ultimately is related to inferences about a population proportion p hat.

Experts have predicted that approximately 1 in 12 tractor-trailer units will be involved in an accident this year.  One reason for this is that 1 in 3 tractor-trailer units has an imminently hazardous mechanical condition, probably related to the braking system on the vehicle.  A survey of 50 tractor-trailer units passing through a weighing station confirmed that 19 had a potentially serious braking system problem.
a)  Do the binomial assumptions hold?

This is the only part of the question I am not understanding.  I know to be binomial it must be independent, must have only 2 outcomes (success and failure), each trail must have the same probability of success, and there must be a fixed n amount of observations.

I believe that the conditions do hold for each, but where I am unsure is what is the probability of success.  Lets assume that having the hazardous breaking system constitutes as a success.  Any help on understanding this question would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always difficult to assess the actual situation from a few sentences in a question, but it seems to me that the author of the question intended a Yes answer to the question about a binomial model. Of course, you would have trouble with independence and bias if trucks enter the scale in convoys of trucks from the
same trucking company, or if police are selecting trucks that seem poorly maintained to be weighed.

The data with 19 in 50 (supposedly randomly chosen) trucks with notable braking problems gives a 95% Agresti confidence interval for $p$ as follows.
The point estimate of $p$ is $p^+ = 21/54 = 0.389$ and the CI is of the form
$$p+ \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{p^+(1-p^+)}{54}},$$
which computes to $(0.259, 0.519).$ This interval is consistent with the
estimate in your second sentence that $p \approx 1/3.$ But it is not a very
tight interval, so the truck-scale data would also be consistent with 30% or 45% of trucks with bad brakes.

*Note:* Agresti CIs for binomial proportions have been shown to have more
nearly the advertised 95% of intervals including the true proportion $p,$ than do traditional intervals using $\hat p = 19/50.\;\;$ [*See this*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I really appreciate it!